# Is there a `index_of` function/method in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

Given an array

```
$values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How do I get the index of `'c'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In puppet `stdlib`, it comes with a function name `values_at`. This does exactly the opposite of what you are looking for. You can reverse this process and create a function of your own quite easily by looking at e.g. `/etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/parser/functions/values_at.rb`.